# How to make the overflow menu icon take up less space?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

On Jelly Bean, the standard action bar overflow icon stretches out to the middle of the battery icon.

However, for the Google Chrome app it is significantly thinner, stretching only as far as the midpoint between the battery and clock.

Changing the overflow icon does not seem to help. Is there another way?

p.s. I am using ActionBarSherlock and targeting Froyo and later.

Comment: Chrome doesn't use the action bar.

Comment: Is there any way to do this when using ABS?